# CommunicationObjectFaultedException occurring only in test environment

Tags: asp.net, wcf, load-balancing

I have a WCF service than in my development and production environments works without any trouble but in my test environment it will occasionally throw a **CommunicationObjectFaultedException**.  This has been very difficult to track down but it seems to happen only after going a long time with out calling it.

The client is a web applictaion running on two load balanced servers, the WCF service is hosted in IIS and running on two load balanced servers.

There is no difference in the WCF configuration between the three environments so I believe there must be something different in the way the servers are set up.  What are some things I can ask my server admins to check? (I don't have proper access to these servers to check stuff myself).

Comment: Do you get the error by performing a certain action or actions?  Sounds like the error is intermittent, but is it always thrown after the same steps (e.g. click the submit order button)?  Also, do you see any more information coming back in the error?

Comment: Also, do your admins see anything in the Event Log that may indicate the cause of the problem?

Comment: Is it HTTP transport? Does it use any kind of session (reliable, security)? Do you reuse proxy for several calls? Is there any Fault before this exception is thrown?

Comment: Also please specify what is long time in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to enable tracing on the server in order to get more detailed error information.  Can you ask your admins to enable that?

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).  I'll update my answer for any additional information you can post.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately this is usually hardly possible in production on live servers.